# Azure disk alert for AKS dynamic disk

Tags: azure-aks, azure-alerts, azure-disk

In AKS we dynamically create and use persistent volume with azure disk.
We setup initial size 20G for s service and we ran out of space.
Is there any way that we can setup a disk alert for dynamic disks to be informed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with agent version ciprod10052020, Container insights integrated agent now supports monitoring PV (persistent volume) usage : [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-persistent-volumes)

**Create metric alerts :**

To alert on system resource issues when they are experiencing peak demand and running near capacity, with Container insights you would create a log alert based on performance data stored in Azure Monitor Logs.
For refernce see [alerts-metric-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-overview) .

Container insights includes Average disc usage % and Average
persistent volume usage% alerts from among many alerts.

- **See** [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-metric-alerts#prerequisites)  and [Steps to enable the metric alerts in
  Azure Monitor from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-metric-alerts#enable-alert-rules)

---

**Log-based alerts:**

Log alerts run queries on Log Analytics data : [Log alerts and    prerquisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/al)

Create an alert rule for container resource    utilization - refer :
[create an alert rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-alerts#create-an-alert-rule)

> **Note**: To create an alert rule for container resource utilization
> requires you to switch to a new log alerts API as described in [switch
> API preference for log alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-api-switch)

To Query to alert when free disk space on cluster nodes exceeds a threshold: see last section of [resource-utilization-log-search-queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-log-alerts#resource-utilization-log-search-queries).